# How to limit a SUM using postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I want to limit the SUM to 2 hours in postgres sql. I dont want to limit the result of the sum, but the value that it is going to sum.

For example, the following table:

In this case, if I SUM('02:20', '01:50', '00:30', '03:00') the result would be 07:30.

```
|CODE |  HOUR |
| --- | ----  |
| 1   | 02:20 |
| 2   | 01:50 |
| 3   | 00:30 |
| 4   | 03:00 |
```

But what i want, is to limit the column HOUR to 02:00. So if the value is > 02:00, it will be replaced with 02:00, only in the SUM.

So the SUM should look like this ('02:00', '01:50', '00:30', '02:00'), and the result would be 06:20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `case` as an argument of the function:

```sql
select sum(case when hour < '2:00' then hour else '2:00' end)
from my_table
```

Test it in [Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c9b284e3416a24b81b938d6d2bf34031)

Answer (score 0):

It's still not perfect, but the idea is this:

> ```
>     select sum(x.anything::time)
>     from (select id, 
>                  time,
>                  case when time <= '02:00' then time::text 
>                  else '02:' || (EXTRACT(MINUTES FROM time::time)::text) 
>                  end as anything
>          from time_table) x
> ```